# How to create a class with an abstract `__init__` method?

Tags: python, abstract-class

I want to create an abstract base class in Python where part of the contract is how instances can be created. The different concrete implementations represent various algorithms that can be used interchangeably. Below is a simplified example (*usual disclaimer* - the real use-case is more complex):

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Type


class AbstractAlgorithm(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, param: int):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_result(self) -> int:
        pass


class ConcreteAlgorithm(AbstractAlgorithm):
    def __init__(self, param: int):
        self._param = param

    def get_result(self) -> int:
        return self._param * 2


def use_algorithm(algorithm: Type[AbstractAlgorithm]) -> int:
    a = algorithm(10)
    return a.get_result()
```

The above works, but has the drawback that I can't call `super().__init__(...)` in `ConcreteAlgorithm.__init__`, which might break certain inheritance scenarios, I think (correct me if I'm wrong here, but calling `super` is important for multiple inheritance, right?). (Strictly speaking `__init__` *can* be called, but with the same signature as the subclass `__init__`, which doesn't make sense).

Python classes are callables, so I could also express it like this:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Callable


class AbstractAlgorithm(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_result(self) -> int:
        pass


class ConcreteAlgorithm(AbstractAlgorithm):
    def __init__(self, param: int):
        self._param = param

    def get_result(self) -> int:
        return self._param * 2


def use_algorithm(algorithm: Callable[[int], AbstractAlgorithm]) -> int:
    a = algorithm(10)
    return a.get_result()


print(use_algorithm(ConcreteAlgorithm))
```

This works and doesn't have the drawback mentioned above, but I do like having the `__init__`-signature in the abstract base class for documentation purposes.

Finally, it is possible to have abstract classmethods, so this approach works as well:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Type


class AbstractAlgorithm(ABC):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def initialize(cls, param: int) -> "AbstractAlgorithm":
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_result(self) -> int:
        pass


class ConcreteAlgorithm(AbstractAlgorithm):
    @classmethod
    def initialize(cls, param: int) -> "ConcreteAlgorithm":
        return cls(param)

    def __init__(self, param: int):
        self._param = param

    def get_result(self) -> int:
        return self._param * 2


def use_algorithm(algorithm: Type[AbstractAlgorithm]) -> int:
    a = algorithm.initialize(10)
    return a.get_result()


print(use_algorithm(ConcreteAlgorithm))
```

This works, but I lose the nice property of using `algorithm` like a callable (it's just more flexible, in case someone actually wants to drop in a function, for example to decide which algorithm to use based on certain parameter values).

So, is there an approach that satisfies all three requirements:

1. Full documentation of the interface in the abstract base class.
2. Concrete implementations usable as callables.
3. No unsafe behavior like not being able to call the base-class `__init__`.

Comment: *"Strictly speaking `__init__` can be called, but with the same signature as the subclass `__init__`, which doesn't make sense"* — can you expand on this more…?

Comment: In multiple inheritance scenario, you can selectively call one of parent's `__init__` by calling `ParentClass.__init__(self, ...)`, but I'm not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: How about accepting `*args` and `**kwargs` in `AbstractAlgorithm.__init__`?

Comment: @Peter The problem is that, because it is abstract, sub-classes need to have exactly the same signature. The base-class is supposed to specify which parameters are required, and because of that, the subclass actually needs to pass those. If the base-class just takes `*args` and `**kwargs` then it defeats the purpose of having an abstract class in the first place. Does that make sense?

Comment: You're declaring the `__init__` as abstract *because* you want to define its signature. Therefore I'm not really following why it's a problem for subclasses to have the same signature or to pass the same parameters to super…?!

Comment: I want subclasses to have a specific signature, but there's no need for them to pass these to the base-class. Normally, subclasses consume their own parameters, and pass the rest on to the base-class using `**kwargs`. However, I might be thinking too complicated here.

Comment: Since the abstract `__init__` defines the signature and all the parameters, all subclasses need to have exactly the same signature and accept exactly the same parameters. So, they *need* to all be passed around to all parents anyway. You can't have it both ways; you can't prescribe a signature but then selectively ignore some of its parameters.

Comment: Aaah - yes, now I've got it. Thanks for untying this knot in my brain :) If you post this as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Strictly speaking `__init__` can be called, but with the same signature as the subclass `__init__`, which doesn't make sense.

No, it makes *perfect* sense.

You're prescribing the signature because you require each child class to implement it exactly. That means you need to *call* it exactly like that as well. Each child class needs to call its `super().__init__` *exactly* according to the abstract definition, passing all defined parameters along.